# Codepen jquery code works fine but when I move it to my wordpress site it no longer works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Alright so here is a link to my Codepen code

https://codepen.io/Kegster/pen/aVJVqW?editors=1111#code-area

and here is a link to the WordPress site that I put my code on

http://www.blackbearlodge.com.php7-34.lan3-1.websitetestlink.com/activities/

The code is exactly the same on my WordPress site.
I would be happy to know either what I can do to fix this or what the animation type is and just find a plugin that could put that exact animation in for me.  Currently just getting fed up with the fact that jQuery is not working properly for me on the site at all.

I tried to update jQuery to the most updated version and that breaks my site (just gets me stuck at a loading screen). I tried to use `.stop(true, true)` to see if it was queuing something up and that didn't work either. I tried a bunch of other things like making the code I built match the proper version. Just can't seem to figure out why nothing will work.  Been at this for 3 days to fix a simple animation.

The theme I am using is i-max (non-pro version)but I am using a child theme that I set up. Which is why there are 2 style.css files. The second one is overwriting the first one so I can make my own style changes.

Comment: very first thing you have added `style.css` file twice

Comment: its a child theme. it overwrites it.  If I delete the original style.css file it will just come back when I update the theme and all the original styles will not carry over.

Comment: hmm thats ok , but why have you included classes for `img-container123` in both of the style sheets shouldn't they be only in the file that you are using to override moreover there are several `CSS` properties that you have removed in your site but they can be seen in the script on codepen.

Answer (score 1):

You have a max-width with set on the img

```
.entry-content img, 
.entry-summary img, 
.comment-content img, 
.widget img, 
.wp-caption {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

To remove, add this into your child theme CSS

```
.entry-content #img-container123 img {
    max-width: none;
}
```

Comment: @Zachary MP Ryan did this fix you issue?

Comment: My issue was resolved with different means but I checked and that would have worked.